# Как в partial передать переменную?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Друзья, подскажите как решить такую ситуацию.

Я определяю переменную экземпляра

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @comment_answer = @answer.comments.new
  end
end
```

Позже ее использую в partial

```
= form_with model: [answer, @comment_answer], class: ‘new-comment’ do |f|
    p
    = f.label :body, ‘Comment’
    p
    = f.text_area :body
    p
    = f.submit ‘add comment’
```

И позже при создании answer я вызываю render этого partial из другого контроллера

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  def publish_answer
    AnswersChannel.broadcast_to(@question,
      ApplicationController.render(
        partial: ‘answers/answer’,
        locals: { question: @question, answer: @answer, current_user: current_user }
      ))
  end
```

Получаю ошибку, потому что партиалу неоткуда взять `@comment_answer`

Вопрос:
как мне в контроллере AnswersController передать в partial переменную экземпляра, чтобы в partial она была доступна как переменная экземпляра, а не как локальная??

Answer (score 0):

Использовать @-переменные в партиалах - плохая идея, и ваш вопрос в очередной раз это доказывает. Самое простое решение в вашем случае:

```
form_with model: [answer, answer.comments.new], class: ‘new-comment’ do |f|
```

И убрать `@comment_answer = @answer.comments.new` из `QuestionsController`, само собой